# How to fix collection() function problem in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

collection() function does not encount all 50 letters, only the one on which the transformation is done.

I have to transform many xml-letters in a csv file with the parameters "Key", "bezeichnung", and "reference" from any letter located in the same folder. When I execute the transformation, I get only the data from the actually transformed file and not from all 50 letters. What is the problem here with the collection() function because everything else works

```
<xsl:variable name="briefe"
        select="collection('./?select=l_*.xml')"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>"Key","Bezeichnung","Referenz"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x000D;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//tei:correspAction[@type='received']/tei:placeName" group-by="@key">
            <xsl:sort select="." />
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//tei:correspAction[@type='received']/tei:placeName)" /><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//tei:correspAction[@type='received']/tei:placeName/@ref" /><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#x000D;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you expect to achieve by solely declaring `<xsl:variable name="briefe"  select="collection('./?select=l_*.xml')"/>` and not using it anywhere, I suspect you want `xsl:for-each-group select="$briefe//tei:correspAction[@type='received']/tei:placeName"`. In general how the `collection` function works depends on the XSLT processor so please include that information in your question.

Comment: hey Martin, that is exactly what I want to do, you found the right path already. I am using right now "XML Editor Oxygen" and the processor is "Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12". You need more information?

Comment: I suppose instead of the use of `//tei:correspAction[@type='received']` inside of the `xsl:for-each-group` (i.e. in the elements like `distinct-values(//tei:correspAction[@type='received']/tei:placeName)` you rather want to use `current-group()` e.g. `distinct-values(current-group()/tei:placeName)`, that change would look at all `tei:correspAction` inside of a group of items from different document while any attempt to use `//` will only look at the document the first item in a group belongs to.